# How can turn a multiline string into arrays and echo a specific index value with bash?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, scripting

bash --version: GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

my multiline var contains this string

```
item1 item2 item3 item4
item1 item2 item3 item4
item1 item2 item3 item4
```

I am trying to output item3 (eventually use it for an API call but just echo it for now) as such:

```
item3
item3
item3
```

This is how I'm attempting to do it:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    printf "${line[2]}"
done < <(printf '%s\n' "$multiline")
```

I currently get nothing. Indicating (to me at least) that printf is not getting an array. But when I loop with something like this:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    for item in ${line[@]}
    do
        echo "$item"
    done
done < <(printf '%s\n' "$EC2")
```

It does echo all 12 items on separate lines as if $line was a legitimate array.
I just want item3 of each line.

Comment: what version of `bash` (`bash --version`) are you using? you state *'there are so many different answers and ways of doing this'* ... show us some of code you've attempted to solve your issue along with the (wrong) output generated by your coding attempts

Comment: the subject mentions `'arrays'` but there's nothing in the description that indicates the use of an array; please update the question with the output from `typeset -p variable_name`  so that we have a clear understanding of the structure of the data we're dealing with

Comment: I have made major edits to my question following your advice @markp-fuso

Comment: Regarding `my multiline var` - having a multiline variable is usually a bad start to any script. Do you NEED to start with that or can we help you do whatever you're trying to do a better way?

Comment: The multiline var is the return from an API call to AWS EC2. Specifically, describe-instances (with 7 "columns") so I am going from there. @EdMorton

Comment: The return you describe is multiple lines, saving all of that together in a variable is a design choice.

Comment: Indeed. i have something like myvar=$(aws api call). You mean to say I can skip this and use the call directly in the loop?

Comment: Yes. I'll update my answer to show that.

Comment: Your variable `line` is a scalar (as we can see from its use in the `read` command), but you later use it as if it were an array (`${line[2]}`).

Comment: That is a n information I am grateful to have @user1934428. Although I have the solution to what I wanted to achieve, I would still appreciate to know how to turn that "scalar" `line` into an Array in my not-working code and only output the  `item3` or `line[2]`

Comment: @SystemCyprus : See the bash man-page for the builtin command `readarray`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ var='item1 item2 item3 item4
item1 item2 item3 item4
item1 item2 item3 item4'

$ echo "$var" | cut -d' ' -f3
item3
item3
item3
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ while read -r _ _ foo _; do
    echo "$foo"
done <<< "$var"
item3
item3
item3
```

or given [your command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72036243/how-can-turn-a-multiline-string-into-arrays-and-echo-a-specific-index-value-with/72036724#comment127286236_72036243):

```
aws api call | cut -d' ' -f3
```

or:

```
while read -r _ _ foo _; do
    echo "$foo"
done < <(aws api call)
```

or:

```
readarray -d $'\n' -t arr < <(aws api call)
printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}" | cut -d' ' -f3
```

etc....

Comment: I do prefer the 2nd approach. It allows me to further manipulate $foo, for another API call that will return item5 and item6 (in a single string) and the last part is to add each of them to the initial "multiline" as "item1 item2 item3 item4 item5 item6" x3

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the `cut -d' ' -f3` approach but using `awk`:

```
$ echo 'item1 item2 item3 item4
item1 item2 item3 item4
item1 item2 item3 item4' | awk '{print $3}'

item3
item3
item3
```

Comment: @SystemCyprus bash is a shell. A shell is a tool to manipulate (create/destroy) files and processes and sequence calls to tools. Awk and cut are tools that can be called from a shell to manipuate text The difference between using awk and cut for this is that cut just prints the 3rd character-separated field while awk splits the input into fields using a regexp search to find the separators, populates various variables (NR, NF, FNR, $0, $1, FILENAME, etc.) and then prints the 3rd field.  So while the output is the same either way awk does significantly more work and so will be slower.

Comment: @SystemCyprus to be clear - awk is a very simple, powerful tool for manipulating text in general while this is the one and only job that `cut` exists to do. Both are mandatory POSIX tools and so will exist on every Unix box.